# Pyautogui declare a variable

Tags: python, pyautogui

In the below statement:-

```
pyautogui.confirm('Choose one.', buttons=['Print A', 'Print B', 'Print C'])
```

In there I would like to add a variable for each button, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: for what these variables ? what do you try do do ?

Comment: if you have variable with text (ie. `var = "Hello"`) then you can concatenate it `buttons=["Print " + var, "Print B"]` and you get button with text `"Print Hello"`

Comment: Okay, that is thank you a lot.

Comment: you can also use `buttons=[variable1, variable2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by "add a variable for each button" but I'd venture to guess you want to correlate a variable or function to a button. You could use a dict for this:

```
a = "You choose A"
b = "You choose B"
c = "You choose C"
choices = {'Print A': a, 'Print B': b, 'Print C': c}
answer = pyautogui.confirm('Choose one.', buttons=list(choices))
#then either print the variable
print(choices[answer])
#or show it in an alert
pyautogui.alert(text=choices[answer], button='OK')
```

Comment: It is exactly what I mean, but it doesnt works for me, im checking it, thank you a lot.

Comment: Works fine for me. I'd need to see what you changed

Comment: C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop>py auto.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto.py", line 6, in <module>
    answer = pyautogui.confirm('Choose one.', buttons=choices)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymsgbox\_native_win.py", line 77, in confirm
    if buttons[0] == pymsgbox.ABORT_TEXT and buttons[1] == pymsgbox.RETRY_TEXT and buttons[2] == pymsgbox.IGNORE_TEXT:
KeyError: 0

Comment: I edited my answer, although it worked for me but I'm on Linux it may be different on windows, maybe you need to turn choices into a list when passing it into the confirm function.

Comment: Okay it works perfectly, thank you a lot and sorry for my ignorance about this.

Comment: Could you please explain me why this if is not working?                 `import pyautogui
a = "You choose A"
b = "You choose B"
c = "You choose C"
choices = {'Print A': a, 'Print B': b, 'Print C': c}
answer = pyautogui.confirm('Choose one.', buttons=list(choices))
#or show it in an alert

if answer == a: 
 
 Print("the if is working")

pyautogui.alert(text=choices[answer], button='OK')`

Comment: Because you’re using `if answer == a :` you need to use `if answer == "Print A":` or `list(choices)[0]`